# parse json response(JavaScriptSerializer) with double quotes using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jsonp

I am using the following code in my aspx(asp.net MVC ViewPage) to get serialized output:

```
var _accountNames = '<%= ViewData["AccountNames"] != null ? new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["AccountNames"]) : null%>';
```

This gives the following result:

```
[{"Name":"My Saving","AccountBalance":-4.2500,"ReferenceId":2},
{"Name":"My Checking","AccountBalance":0.0000,"ReferenceId":3},
{"Name":"Undeposited Funds","AccountBalance":113.6600,"ReferenceId":2},
{"Name":"Star Account "Trust"","AccountBalance":0.0000,"ReferenceId":50}]
```

In the above result, the Account (Star Account "Trust") has double quotes in it. It gives `"missing } after property list"` error, while using eval. Even using JSON parse gives error.

I am using this result to bind the dropdown options as:

```
 var k = JSON.parse(_accountNames.replace(/'/g, '"'));
 if (k != null && k.length > 0) {
    var options = '';
    options += '<option value="">' + "--Select Account--" + '</option>';
    for (var i = 0; i < k.length; i++) {
       options += '<option value="' + k[i].AccountNameType + '">' + k[i].Name + ' $(' + k[i].AccountBalance + ')' + '</option>';
    }
}
$("select#DepositToddl").html(options);
```

How can i parse the result has double quotes in it? Please suggest.

Comment: You can't, because it's not valid JSON. You need to fix the JSON. `JavaScriptSerializer` seems to handle this correctly for me. Not sure why it isn't working for you.

Comment: @Craig, Can u post how you used JavaScriptSerializer. Am i missing something in my above code?

Answer (score 1):

Use `HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`.

Your server tag will become:

```
var _accountNames = '<%= ViewData["AccountNames"] != null ? HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ViewData["AccountNames"])) : null%>';
```

Comment: Nice! Exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old, but since Craig didn't post an example ... I figured I would.

As noted by Craig's comment to your question, your JSON is bad.

If you drop this into LINQPad as a C# statement you'll get the quotes escaped correctly:

(You'll need System.Runtime.Serialization and System.Web.Extensions.)

```
Accounts accounts = new Accounts();
accounts.AccountNames = new List<Account>();
accounts.AccountNames.Add(new Account() { Name = "My Saving", AccountBalance = -4.25, ReferenceId = 2});
accounts.AccountNames.Add(new Account() { Name = "My Checking", AccountBalance = 0, ReferenceId = 3});
accounts.AccountNames.Add(new Account() { Name = "Undeposited Funds", AccountBalance = 113.66, ReferenceId = 2});
accounts.AccountNames.Add(new Account() { Name = "Star Account \"Trust\"", AccountBalance = 0, ReferenceId = 50});

JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
jsonSerializer.Serialize(accounts.AccountNames).Dump();
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
public class Accounts {
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
    public List<Account> AccountNames { get; set; }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract]
public class Account {
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
    public double AccountBalance { get; set; }
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
    public int ReferenceId { get; set; }
```

That returns the following JSON data:

```
[{"Name":"My Saving","AccountBalance":-4.25,"ReferenceId":2},
{"Name":"My Checking","AccountBalance":0,"ReferenceId":3},
{"Name":"Undeposited Funds","AccountBalance":113.66,"ReferenceId":2},
{"Name":"Star Account \"Trust\"","AccountBalance":0,"ReferenceId":50}]
```

You might have solved this already, but it would be interesting to see how your ViewData is populated. Is it just a string created on the fly, or is it really based on an object?